# Dynamic Import from url get param in reactjs/typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying the app from https://github.com/agentcooper/react-pdf-highlighter but I have a problem when I want to get the typescript file from get url param.

I can display according to the get param but all typescript files must be included in the code. i want to include typescript file according to get param request. so no need server no need to load all files

```
import type { IHighlight, NewHighlight } from "./react-pdf-highlighter";

const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(document.location.search);
const bookcode = searchParams.get("kode_buku");
const anotator = searchParams.get("kode_reviewer");
console.log(bookcode);

const mydir = "./" + bookcode;
let str_anotator = String(anotator);


import { testHighlights as _jhon } from "./anotasi/john";
import { testHighlights as _joe } from "./anotasi/joe";
import { testHighlights as _leo } from "./anotasi/leo";
import { testHighlights as _cristiano } from "./anotasi/cristiano";
import { testHighlights as _bujang } from "./anotasi/bujang";
import { testHighlights as _larry } from "./anotasi/larry";

import { Spinner } from "./Spinner";
import { Sidebar } from "./Sidebar";
import "./style/App.css";

let testHighlights: Record<string, Array<IHighlight>> = _raditya;

if (anotator == "john") { testHighlights = _john }
if (anotator == "joe") { testHighlights = _joe }
if (anotator == "leo") { testHighlights = _leo }
if (anotator == "cristiano") { testHighlights = _cristiano }
if (anotator == "bujang") { testHighlights = _bujang }
if (anotator == "larry") { testHighlights = _larry }


console.log(testHighlights);
```

i wish fetching typescript file could be done based on get url param only, because if at this time the load process will be slow if all typescript files must be loaded.